# Mongoid: How to have distinct fields in User & Message n to m relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have got two models like following:

```
class User
include Mongoid::Document

   has_many_and_belongs_to :messages
```

end

```
class Message
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many_and_belongs_to :users

  field :text
  field :visited, type: Boolean, default: false
end
```

As far as i know when this template implements message fields are common among users. What i want to have here is `visited` field be distinct for every user to work with. Any idea how would that applicable? `I have an alternative such as a middle model to save user & message id with desire field but that seems messy`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the `has_and_belongs_to_many` relation yourself. This way you can customize the class used to link a `User` and a `Message`:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :user_messages
end

class Message
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :user_messages
end

class UserMessage
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :message

  field :visited, type: Boolean, default: false

  scope :visited,   -> { where(visited: true) }
  scope :unvisited, -> { where(visited: false) }
end
```

Then you can do:

```
u = User.new
m = Message.new

u.user_messages.build(message: m, visited: true)
u.user_messages.build(message: m, visited: false)
u.user_messages.count
=> 2
u.user_messages.visited.count
=> 1
u.user_messages.unvisited.count
=> 1
```

More information about this kind of association from Rails Guide [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many).

Note that the `UserMessage` class name is quite annoying. You could instead use a different naming such as `Conversation`:

```
class User
  has_many :messages
end

class Conversation
  has_many :messages
end

class Message
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :conversation

  field :visited, type: Boolean, default: false
end
```

Which is used nicely:

```
u = User.new
c = Conversation.new
u.messages.build(conversation: c)
```

Comment: Thanks, But dude, `visited` here is for every single user shows whether message is read or not, and here i want to send message more than one user.